# Why is Math.atan2 not working correctly for me?

Tags: javascript, math, rotation, paperjs, atan2

I'm trying to create a simple game where the rectangle in the center always points towards the mouse. For some reason, when I use Math.atan2 I get weird values that never go above 3 for the angle...

[Here's the sketch with my code](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/XZFNb4MwDIb/ipUdChKNaC+bqHraGWnaDjuUHjJwS0RmVyGlsIr/vkBphepDFDvP669cBalfFIn4qtDlpYhEzsXgN8rCyagOLWyB8AIfypXyE3On6GgwuGYE3mpnucJ3NmwTWLysR1tE88dvXbgygVU8RQ/amIfgdbSHQP9hArtVHEfwFu+naI7k0NONxou8ORn14SajjA5nyp1mAqaUzzWm3GCAjYdCmFocJilaP8UYlifW/mxhOc8n280M7p7g7gnuZrBlp8YGtpAOG1J+P+ug6CJfM5y4aQymmg1Kw8fgrroTt03LWbL71QO9/5Ufi6oau6lFstv3/w==)

```
function onMouseMove(event) {
    var dx = event.point.x - view.center.x;
    var dy = event.point.y - view.center.y;
    var rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

    console.log(rotation);
    player.rotation = rotation;
}
```

It'd be great if someone could spot what I'm doing wrong or even edit the sketch so that it works :)

Comment: What do you want to do here? Right now you are just taking the arc tangent of two points based on their position on the screen, not the `dx` or `dy` or the mouse position itself. `Math.atan2` appears to be working fine here.

Comment: I want it so that the rectangle rotates to face the mouse. I guess I'm missing something/doing the wrong thing?

Comment: Please paste the code.  I don't click on external links.  Do you understand trigonometry?  The tangent function?  How to transform points?

Comment: Not sure about paper js but if it's expecting degrees, multiply math.tan(x,y) * 180/math.pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three things here:

1. Rotation adds to the current rotation with paper.js, to disable it you need to set `applyMatrix: false`
2. Rotation is in degrees and not radians. you need to multiply your `atan2` by `180 / Math.PI`
3. You should be using `player.center` and not `view.center`

Here is the code you can use:

```
var player = new Path.Rectangle({
    strokeColor: '#222222',
    strokeWidth: 10,
    fillColor: '#777777',
    size: [100, 80],
    center: view.center,
    applyMatrix: false
});

function onMouseMove(event) {
    var dx = event.point.x - player.center.x;
    var dy = event.point.y - player.center.y;
    var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / Math.PI;

    console.log(angle);
    player.rotation = angle;
}
```